# My sorting algorithm ignores lines of code,why?

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop

Ive tried to use an 'odd' sorting algorithm just to see if i can manage make it work, basically the algorithm finds the smallest number and places it first, then it repeats this loop but starting from the second number, ignoring the already sorted one completely, but for some reason it seems to not ignore the first sorted number and constantly swaps it out.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    int min;
    int a[10];
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     cout<<"a["<< i <<"]=";
    cin>>a[i];
    }
    min=a[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
     for(j=i;j<n;j++)
     {
      if(min>a[j])
      min=a[j];
     }
    a[j]=a[i];
    a[i]=min;
    min=100;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<a[i];
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `min=100;`? It's completely arbitrary and will very likely lead to "weird" results in the `if(min>a[j])` check

Comment: If you are using c++ there is really no reason not to use variable length ``std::vector`` over c-style arrays.

Comment: Explain to your nearest rubber duck what is the value of `j` when the execution reaches the line `a[j]=a[i];`

Comment: Your problem would become more self evident if you stopped using c-style variable declarations and wrote smaller, meaningful functions. Declare your variables as late as possible and don't cram everything into main.